# Using Isotope plugin with requirejs

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, require, jquery-isotope

Ive added the Isotope plugin using these instructions: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/appendix.html#requirejs

Heres my code:

```
this.social = new Isotope('#latest-news', {
    itemSelector: '.social-item',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    sortBy: 'text',
    getSortData: {
       'text': '.text'
    }
});
```

i then try to insert elements later on like so:

```
that.social( 'insert', elements );
```

but get the following error (On the insert function):

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

If i do a **console.log(this.social)** it does return an isotope object.

How can i call the 'insert' function, or any function for that matter? Otherwise where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went through the source code for a while, when using requirejs the insert method becomes:

**that.social.insert( elements );**

Basically use the **vanilla JS** versions of the methods.